# Execute rest of code when redirected page loads?

Tags: javascript

I'm making a game script in Javascript but I've run into a slight problem.

The page is redirected fine, but I can't run the code after it on the other page. Is there a way I can check for the redirect to have happened, the page to have loaded, and then execute the rest of the code?

Code is below:

```
    window.open("http://en73.tribalwars.net/game.php?screen=train","_self");
// redirects to 'troop building' page

window.onload = allInOne()
  {   
    unit_build_block.set_max('archer');
// select maximum troops player is able to build with current resources
  }
```

Comment: you already have window.onload in your code so you know that when a new document is loaded the code in window.onload will run. do you want to track if the page is loaded after specifically you have redirected? then you can add a url parameter like "&redirect=1" and check it in javascript (location.search)

Comment: Are both webpages in same domain? If they are, you can communicate between them but if they aren't, there is a cross-domain problem...

Comment: Volkan - I want to redirect to a specific page and then run allInOne(). Bommox, no, they are not.

Comment: @Bommox The same origin policy would only come into play if he had both pages open at the same time, in this case the OP is redirecting the page.  So the current page would be unloaded preventing communication to the new page.

Comment: @user3280504, include your allInOne method on the page you've redirected to.  You cannot run it on the redirect destination from the  origin page context.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not control the page that is redirected to. Does this mean that what I wish to do is not possible?

Comment: @user3280504 not with a redirect.  If both pages are the same domain you can use `window.open` which will allow you to invoke JS on the training page

Comment: The script is run from a link in a 'quick bar' on the game's site, in the format: Javascript: $.getScript("http://www.example.com/example.js"); void(0);              It then redirects to another site on the game's domain.